# Making a clean high quality GIF with fix colorbar for multiple xarray plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, gif, animated-gif, colorbar

I want to make a gif out of multiple plots from a xarray. I need the colorbar to be identical in all of the plots to track the change. It is easy to fix the numbers on the colorbar ticks but the color keeps changing. Somehow making GIF is messing with colors! How I can fix this?

```
#making GIF
fns_image=glob(save_image_dir+'/'+'*')
fns_image.sort()
with imageio.get_writer(save_gif_dir+gif_name, mode='I') as writer:
for filename in fns_image: 
    print(filename)
    image = imageio.imread(filename,)
    writer.append_data(image)
```

I appreciate suggestions[image].

Comment: I would suggest to produce a [mcve]. This would first of all allow to find out if this happens with matplotlib alone, or if it's a cartopy problem, or maybe even a gif compression problem?

Comment: Is there a way to attach a small netcdf to this question? Or Maybe upload the data somewhere and share the link?

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue without external data.

Comment: I looked at all of the created images! It seems that the problem is in the GIF making! I added the gif making part to the code! Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Without an example to reproduce your error, it is difficult to help you.

Answer (score 4):

The 'levels' argument (as an integer) will only supply the number of levels, but always scale to the data.  To set a specified range of data to be mapped, you can supply a custom array of equally spaced data.  The length of the array will correspond to the number of levels.

For your case, you should change levels to `levels = np.linspace(min_value, max_value, <number of levels>)` instead of the range function.

**EDIT** with reproducible example:

```
import xarray as xr
import os, glob
import imageio

png_dir = '<your_directory>'
airtemps = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature')

# Plots with variable (scaling) colorbar
for i in np.arange(25):
    plt.figure()
    plt.contourf(airtemps.air[i,:,:], levels = 25), plt.colorbar()
    plt.savefig(png_dir + 'air_temp_' + str(i) +'.png')    

max_temp = airtemps.air[:25,:,:].max()
min_temp = airtemps.air[:25,:,:].min()  

# Plots with Fixed colorbar    
for i in np.arange(25):
    plt.figure()
    plt.contourf(airtemps.air[i,:,:], levels = np.linspace(min_temp,max_temp,25)), plt.colorbar()
    plt.savefig(png_dir + 'fixed_cb_air_temp_' + str(i) +'.png')

variable_cb_images = glob.glob(png_dir + 'air*')
fixed_cb_images = glob.glob(png_dir + ('fix*'))  

var = [imageio.imread(file) for file in variable_cb_images]
fix = [imageio.imread(file) for file in fixed_cb_images]

imageio.mimsave(png_dir + '/movie_variable_cb.gif', var, fps = 10)
imageio.mimsave(png_dir + '/movie_fixed_cb.gif', fix, fps = 10)
```

[image: Variable Color Bar]

[image: Fixed Color Bar]

Comment: Same issue as previous! Levels are defined before the loop so no matter what method is used, it is similar for all figures!

Comment: Can you paste the code you used with levels set with a linspace? Levels set with linspace makes a static colorbar.

Comment: The problem is in gif making! Figures have the same colorbar apparently! Somehow the GIF is changing the colors!

Comment: That is pretty good, thanks! But the lat-long don't carry over with matplotlib.countousf() or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I used PIL instead of imageio to read figures and make the GIF, the colors are consistent now!

```
from PIL import Image  
img, *imgs = [Image.open(f) for f in fns_image]
img.save(fp=save_gif_dir+gif_name+'1.gif', format='GIF', append_images=imgs,
     save_all=True, duration=200, loop=0)
```

> 

Answer (score 2):

I did a workaround using imagio and FFmpeg to create the gif.
Creating a gif using imagio.mimsave always causes artifacts in the colorbar for me. Using PIL also downgraded the quality of my gif.
My solution is to create mp4 file from the images, which has a better quality, and in case that gif is all you need, you can convert it with FFmpeg from mp4 to gif.

```
import os, imageio
images_paths = <your_images_paths>
out_file_name = <your_output_file_name>
# read images with imageio
images = [imageio.imread(file_path) for file_path in images_paths]
# save image as .mp4 file
imagio.mimsave(f'{out_file_name}.mp4', images)
# create .gif from .mp4 using FFmpeg
os.system(f'ffmpeg -i {out_file_name}.mp4 {out_file_name}.gif')
# remove the created .mp4 file
os.system(f'rm {out_file_name}.mp4')
```